# How to batch download all files in a Volafile.io room?

Tags: terminal, macos, command-line, homebrew

> Volafile.io Live Filesharing & Chat

Example URL: `https://volafile.io/r/$ID`.

There is [Feature request: Download all the content of a room in a .zip file. #117](https://github.com/Volafile/volafile-bugs/issues/117). I don't wish to depend on that feature request.

How to download all files in a Volafile.io room? I prefer a command line solution (Open Source, installable by `homebrew`), something like what's `youtube-dl` for YouTube.

`Jdwonloader` at the moment doesn't support Volafile.io. If there is no CLI solution, how to do that with GUI?

Comment: Could you provide a real URL so I can test against some CLI Utilities?

Answer (score 2):

You can paste this JavaScript in Chrome’s developer console:

```js
// Get all download links
var fileArray = document.getElementsByClassName('file_left_part')
// Loop through all the file links and append a new link to the DOM
// with a download attribute
for (var i = 0; i < fileArray.length; i++) {
    var dlLink = document.createElement('a')
    dlLink.download = ''
    dlLink.href = fileArray[i].href
    dlLink.className = 'filetype_download'
    document.body.appendChild(dlLink)
}
// Select all the download links we just created
var dlLinkArray = document.getElementsByClassName('filetype_download')
// Create a function to click on each link in series with a delay
// of 2.5 seconds (volafile will rate limit you otherwise)
function clickIt(i) {
    setTimeout(function() { dlLinkArray[i].click() }, i * 2500)
}
// Run our click function on every download link
for (var i = 0; i < dlLinkArray.length; i++) {
    clickIt(i)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! There's enough going on here that some comments or an explanation might be nice; if you could, can you add something?

Comment: Added some comments to explain whats going on

Answer (score 2):

This is the only way I've been able to accomplish downloading all or some files from Volafile using JDownloader:

1. Use Firefox.
2. Make sure [JDownloader](https://jdownloader.org/) is running.
3. Get the Firefox add-on [Link Gopher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/link-gopher/).
4. While in Volafile, filter out the items you want using the search box at the top.
5. Next, run Link Gopher and click “all links”. This will open a new Firefox tab with the links from Volafile.
6. While in the Link Gopher screen, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (copy) and all the links will be transferred to the linkgrabber screen of JDownloader where you can be selective or just download them all.  If you got this far, you'll figure out all the things you can and cannot do with this arrangement.

Someone posted about a Download Them All Firefox add-on – it’s either not available or doesn't work… I’ve tried them all.  Link Gopher works really well.  It also lets you highlight the links you want before you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: By the way, the linkgopher plugin is for firefox and NOT jdownloader. Sorry I didn't make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox
Downthemall! extension (free from mozilla)

Highlight all files you want to get.
Right click and select download selection.

Alternatively, you can just right click, tell it to download all, pick the all files filter and download folder and watch it go.  It will even skip or rename duplicate files as you request.

Works perfect and is free.